# Excel: Moved large block of cells - Lost a couple of cell references - why?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

Excel 2007: I had moved the main formula block out of the way, on the same sheet.
Then reduced the column & row sizes outside of the work area.
Everything worked.

I needed to modify the hidden code, so dragged it back to a workable area.
3 simple cell references were lost in the formulas.
=(INDIRECT("'Carb-Data'!"&"B"&BV5))

BV5 was lost (another like this)

=IF(OR((CW6-$C$10)<=0),(0),(CW6-$C$10))

CW6 was lost

Clicking undo didn't fix the problem - the data returned to its previous position, but the refs were lost

I simply re-entered the cell references and 'filled' the columns.
Everything works again.

I'd like to understand why these cell refs were lost when moving the data, when all others weren't.
Eg. =F6&"_N1"

F6 was not lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't give you an exhaustive answers, however a few reasons:

- All your references you've mentioned to be lost were relative references, so moving the cell containing the formula "moves" the reference too.

  - e.g. if your formula is in CW10 and you move it to CW8, then reference changes CW6 -> CW4
  - however, if you move CW10 -> CW1 then reference should change CW6 -> CW-3 which is definitely a wrong address, Excel converts it to `#Ref`
  - (in short you shift referred cells out of the sheet)
- By moving a lot of cells, it's easy to loose track of referred ranges, if you delete a referred cell (delete entire row / column or delete and shift cells up / left), Excel will also give you `#Ref` error

Comment: Thanks Mate - Copy and paste works - Moving the block retains the top row reference - the 2nd row loses the ref - undoing the move fails - the ref still lost - I must remember to copy and paste (the failed undo is strange though)